# Restrict user access to a specific site

Tags: security, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

I have setup two ASP.NET core 2.0 applications which uses Azure B2C for authentication. The first site is used for desktop users and the second site is used for mobile users. Users who have access to the mobile site should not have access to the desktop site, however I am unsure how to configure B2C to restrict users to one domain.

The only solution I can come up with is to add a permission 'can-access-desktop' and 'can-access-mobile' and add a filter on my server side to use the request origin to check whether the user has the can-access-mobile or can-access-desktop permission.

I feel there is a better way to do this or a way my approach could be improoved?

Comment: Hi @simondefreeze. Are you using built-in or custom policies?

Comment: Hey @chris-padgett I am using custom policies. Thanks